# After updating `Xcode 6` from `beta4` to `beta6`, my App crashes on button click action

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6-beta6

I'm writing iOS swift project, today i updated `Xcode 6` from `beta4` to `beta6`. It compiles well, but when i press button, it prints "lol" in console and crashes. There is my code:

```
@IBOutlet var emailField : UITextField!

@IBAction func signInPressed () {
println("lol")
let email = emailField.text as NSString
println("lol")
}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: what is the crash message you get

Comment: dyld`dyld_fatal_error:
0x2be430c4: trap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clean your project and build again.